# bookmarks.html の仕様書

Tags: javascript, html, browser

#### 質問内容

下記ブラウザにはブックマーク(お気に入り)をbookmarks.htmlにエクスポートする機能があります。

- Google Chrome
- Firefox
- Microsoft Edge
- Internet Explorer

各々のbookmarks.htmlのフォーマットには類似性があると思いますが、「bookmarks.htmlのWeb標準の仕様書」となるURLがわかりましたら、教えてください。
(Web標準の仕様がないようでしたら、ブラウザベンダーのドキュメントでも構いません)

#### 質問の背景

bookmarks.htmlをFile API経由でインポートする機能を実装しようとしています。

#### 参考リンク

- [ブックマークを HTML ファイルにエクスポートする | Firefox ヘルプ](https://support.mozilla.org/ja/kb/export-firefox-bookmarks-to-backup-or-transfer)
- [ブックマークと設定をインポートする - Google Chrome ヘルプ](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/96816?hl=ja)
- [富士通Q&A - [Microsoft Edge] 「お気に入り」をバックアップする方法を教えてください。 - FMVサポート : 富士通パソコン](https://www.fmworld.net/cs/azbyclub/qanavi/jsp/qacontents.jsp?PID=7011-1201)
- [Internet Explorer のお気に入りを新しい PC に移動する](https://support.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/internet-explorer-%E3%81%AE%E3%81%8A%E6%B0%97%E3%81%AB%E5%85%A5%E3%82%8A%E3%82%92%E6%96%B0%E3%81%97%E3%81%84-pc-%E3%81%AB%E7%A7%BB%E5%8B%95%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B-a03f02c7-e0b9-5d8b-1857-51dd70954e47)

Comment: @metropolis さん、情報提供ありがとうございます。
私の解釈に誤りがなければ、「json仕様の質問」に読めましたが、合っているでしょうか。
回答のリンク先から https://www.jeffersonscher.com/ffu/bookbackreader.html のソースを読みましたが、「jsonlz4 or .json」をインポートし、「bookmarks.html」にエクスポートする機能に読めました。
私の目的は、bookmarks.htmlのインポートで、bookmarks.htmlのparserを実装しようとしています。

Comment: @metropolis さん、承知しました。他に発見がありましたら、情報提供いただけますと幸いです。

Comment: Internet Explorer に関して次のページは参考になりませんか？：[Netscape Bookmark File Format (Internet Explorer) | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa753582(v=vs.85))

Comment: @supa さん、情報ありがとうございます。
SuikaWikiは私も見たのですが、「個人サイトであること」「Netscape時代のbookmark書式」の2点から参考情報から外しておりました。

Comment: think49 さんと同意見です。今のところ一番信頼性が高そうなのは microsoft docs のみでしたので、そちらのリンクだけコメントしました（調べてみましたが、他ブラウザはフォーラムを見ても特に情報がなさそうです）

Comment: 検証したところ、Google Chrome/FirefoxはMSサイトの情報通り、Unix timeでした。
JavaScriptの new Date(add_date * 1000) で追加日時を復元できます。
Google ChromeではLAST_MODIFIED属性がフォルダのみに適用(ブックマークアイテムにはADD_DATE属性のみ)、FirefoxはブックマークアイテムにもLAST_MODIFIED属性がありました。
もう少し情報を待ってみますが、現行ブラウザの細かな違いは手探りで探す事になりそうですね…。

Answer (score 3):

Edge、Firefox、Chromeでブックマークをエクスポートすると、`<!DOCTYPE NETSCAPE-Bookmark-file-1>`というドキュメントタイプになっており、Netscape Navigatorの時から使われるフォーマットのようです。古い非公式なドキュメントがありましたので、歴史的な所は下記が参考になると思います。

[NETSCAPE-Bookmark-file-1](https://wiki.suikawiki.org/n/NETSCAPE-Bookmark-file-1$331)

ベンダーが出しているドキュメントとしては、IEの物になりますが、下記を見つけました。

[Netscape Bookmark File Format (Internet Explorer) | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa753582(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

MDNやChromium関係のドキュメントは見つけられませんでした。

仕様書やRFCがあるとか、何かドキュメントとしてまとまっていると言うよりは、Netscape時代の物がデファクトスタンダードとして他のブラウザでも採用されたという形のようです。そのため、ブラウザ間で差異がある可能性がありますが、それは一つ一つ確認する以外は無いかと思われます。

Comment: raccy さん、情報ありがとうございます。
今のところ、一番詳しい資料はSuikaWiki(個人サイト)ということですね。
ブラウザベンダー系ではNetscape Navigator後継(Firefox)の開発元のMDNにあると思っていたので、Microsoftに情報があるのは驚きました。
他に新しい情報がないか待ってから、質問をクローズしたいと思います。
WHATWG https://spec.whatwg.org/ がまとめてくれていれば安心でしたが、最新ブラウザに対応した情報は自分で調査する以外にないかもしれないですね…。